# <fb:comments> is displaying different layouts according to the href used inside. Why?

Tags: dynamic, facebook-comments

I'm trying to understand why two different layouts are displayed by the  placeholder, according to the href parameter used inside of it. Quick example - say I'm using http://example.com/ as the href resource - I'll get the usual header before the comments, with the number of comments on the left and "Add a comment" on the right. However, when I'm changing the href to the one I really need (i.e. the page where the box resides), I only get a list of comments, no number of comments, no "add a comment". Have a look at this to see what I mean: http://popz.ro/comments.php?aid=1

Why, oh why? (something to do with the app I've registered?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I go to your link, I see a comments area as well as an input box to add new comments.

This appears to be correct based upon the plugin code used:

```
            <fb:comments width="950" href="http://popz.ro/comments.php?aid=1"></fb:comments>
```

I also see you've got the og meta tags specificed too, which will help:

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="Popz" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://popz.ro/comments.php?aid=1" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://popz.ro/png/fpopz.png" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Popz | fresh de stiri" />
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="584603173" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="277079292362391" />
```

Also the app_id matches between the `FB.init()` code as well as that specified in the meta tags. So there's no problem there.

I see only 2 comments, and the default is 2, so it's not going to show the # of comments until you go over that amount.

Comment: Well, actually you know what - I think you're right, it's a mixed issue of moderated comments and low nr of comments.